# Can I ask several related questions in a single thread?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

I have several physics questions, all of which are about the sloshing mode of water.  Should I ask all the questions in a single thread, or create separate threads?

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/11305)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each question should go in its own thread.

One question per post allows users to answer each question individually with the proper comments and voting for each question.

Please do not combine multiple inquiries into one question.

Comment: multiple questions can be linked together however, in an organic way like "When I asked [previous question][1] it brought up another related issue.."

Comment: (to make Jeff's example more complete: `[previous question](http://link.to.it)`)