# Protocol for asking closely related, but different questions?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I ask several related questions in a single thread?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-i-ask-several-related-questions-in-a-single-thread)

What do you do if you want to ask a second, related but different question?
(The original question can be your own question, or someone else’s question.)
Also, considerable time may have elapsed.

Start a new question?
Put it in an answer box?
Put it in a comment?
I see no good answer, but my intuition would be to ask a new question.
Advice, please?

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-i-ask-several-related-questions-in-a-single-thread

Comment: In brief: start a new question. Don't ask questions in comments except to clarify the original question, and _never_ ask a question in an "answer"