# I asked way too many questions at once, now I must pay the price

Tags: discussion

Previously, I wrote the following question [Has anyone formally tested Josh Pellicer's theory on human sexual behavior?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9300/has-anyone-formally-tested-josh-pellicers-theory-on-human-sexual-behavior). This was a question I wrote with a lot of material from the work in question. This question contained 6 sub-questions to answer for an overarching one question. Oddly enough, the question received great attention, so I placed a bounty on it, and then I received a very well thought out answer which answered all sub-questions.

Then the Curious George that I am, I wrote another question [What are the limitations of superconductors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/what-are-the-limitations-of-superconductors), then I got into a lot of trouble. Mostly because I made an inappropriate comment: "Let's get inquisitive." I am sorry, I was listening to a lot of funky music over the weekend, while I was learning to program, and then I found myself getting down on my keyboard.

I think either the question did not have enough supporting material, no bounty placed, nonproductive commenting, or too many sub-questions. I know the question is on hold, so I will be unable to fix it in time, so what should I do in the future to avoid this issue?

Comment: Your first question was on a completely separate site, so it doesn't really tell you what to expect on this site.

Answer (score 8):

Closing a question doesn't mean you are in trouble. It means that your question, in its current state, does not meet the standards of the site. This label can be removed if you edit your question. I also don't think anyone was influenced by your "lets get inquisitive" comment, though I do not believe that's really an appropriate response to glance's comment.

Personally, I voted to close your question as Too Broad because you've got 7 questions, some of which can actually be found with a simple Google search (which suggests you just rushed out and asked without trying to find the information in the normal means). We prefer [**one question per post**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-i-ask-several-related-questions-in-a-single-thread), though we sometimes loosen this rule and allow one or two *closely related* questions in a post.

If you reduced the list of questions to the aforementioned one or two *closely related* ones, I'd be willing to nominate it for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you've run into the "problems" that arise by letting each community set its own standards. Your question on cogsci.SE was allowed and well received despite having multiple questions because that's how that community responds. This community, however, does not generally keep open posts with several questions in them (unless the questions are so inter-related that asking them independently would mean none of them make sense).

All of the questions you asked could be asked as independent questions. That is not to say anything about the quality of them as individual questions nor is it to say whether they would be considered good or not (just copy-pasting each one into its own question would not be good, it's basically just trivia and not asking about the *how* or *why* the numbers are what they are).

As for being in trouble, having the question on hold, etc. there is no need to repeat what [Kyle said in his answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6557/6634).